# Plot differences between the 1977 version and 1997 rewrite of "Demon Seed"

Tags: textual-history, demon-seed, dean-koontz

What's the difference in terms of plot between the 1977 version and 1997 rewrite of *Demon Seed* by Dean Koontz? Spoilers are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Demon_Seed_(novel)&oldid=948282086):

> The revised version is written entirely from the point of view of Proteus, who recounts the novel's events at some unspecified point in the future, after his imprisonment of Susan has been exposed.
>
> Susan is portrayed as a much stronger and more self-sufficient character than in the original book, while Proteus, in contrast, is characterized in a much more childish way. Unlike in the earlier version, Proteus never explicitly rapes or molests Susan, and uses a human servant (a mentally unstable man that he has somehow managed to gain control over) rather than the pseudopods and subliminal manipulation he relied upon originally. The child in this version is described as an insectoid human instead of a cyborg. Unlike her counterpart in the 1973 edition, this version of Susan never attempts suicide.

Comment: I've edited in information from the Wikipedia article. You can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].